# Asking about threading, arrays and cache memory

Tags: java, oop, list, synchronized, thread-local

I hope in a good manner :-)
I wrote this piece of code.
What I wished to do, is to build something like "cache".
I assumed that I had to watch for different threads, as might many calls get to that class, so I tried the ThreadLocal functionality.
Base pattern is
   have "MANY SETS of VECTOR"
   The vector holds something like:
   VECTOR.FieldName = "X"
   VECTOR.FieldValue= "Y"
So many Vector objects in a set. Different set for different calls from different machines, users, objects.

```
 private static CacheVector instance = null;
        private static SortedSet<SplittingVector> s = null;
        private static TreeSet<SplittingVector> t = null;
        private static ThreadLocal<SortedSet<SplittingVector>> setOfVectors = new ThreadLocal<SortedSet<SplittingVector>>();

        private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<SplittingVector> {
     public int compare(SplittingVector a, SplittingVector b) {
         return 1;
     }
     // No need to override equals.
        }

        private CacheVector() {
        }

        public static SortedSet<SplittingVector> getInstance(SplittingVector vector) {
     if (instance == null) {
         instance = new CacheVector();
         //TreeSet<SplittingVector>
         t = new TreeSet<SplittingVector>(new MyComparator());
         t.add(vector);
         s = Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(t);//Sort the set of vectors
         CacheVector.assign(s);
     } else {
         //TreeSet<SplittingVector> t = new TreeSet<SplittingVector>();
         t.add(vector);
         s = Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(t);//Sort the set of vectors
         CacheVector.assign(s);
     }
     return CacheVector.setOfVectors.get();
        }

        public SortedSet<SplittingVector> retrieve() throws Exception {
     SortedSet<SplittingVector> set = setOfVectors.get();
     if (set == null) {
         throw new Exception("SET IS EMPTY");
     }
     return set;
        }

        private static void assign(SortedSet<SplittingVector> nSet) {
     CacheVector.setOfVectors.set(nSet);
        }
```

So... I have it in the attach and I use it like this:

```
CachedVector cache = CachedVector.getInstance(bufferedline);
```

The nice part: Bufferedline is a splitted line based on some delimiter from data files. Files can be of any size.

So how do you see this code? Should I be worry ?
I apologise for the size of this message!

Comment: Your singleton is not thread-safe.

Comment: Use `101010` button to format code snippet

Comment: And the usage of `ThreadLocal` is discouraged (see Effective Java 2nd…).

Comment: @khachik: Sorry, first preview was nice formated. Now?

Comment: @PartlyClody: Isn't TreadLocal supposed to be the container for keeping between thread sessions object in distance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing correct multi-threaded code is not that easy (i.e. your singleton fails to be), so try to rely on existing solutions if posssible. If you're searching for a thread-safe Cache implementation in Java, check out this [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28int,%20float,%20boolean%29). You can use it to implement a [LRU cache](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/6.htm). And [collections.synchronizedMap()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29). can make this thread-safe.

Comment: Is it possible to describe in natural way, what is the fault on this code? I am assuming at least the singleton, as singleton should be ok.

Comment: So something after that goes wacko. In the docs however, Vectors are synchronized themselves...so  shouldn't I be safe to just load synchronized classes with a "tread-session" ?